# VS2017 Parsing Error XAML Special Character Entities

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, encoding, visual-studio-2017

I got this error en VS2017 Compiler when i use an spacial character on an XAML file, for example:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="lblProductLineName" Content="Línea de Producto"/>
```

When i compile i got this error:

> Error=>   'Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 26, position
>   87.' XML is not valid.

I opened this project on VS2010 don't have that error.
I'm  trying to change to use HTML format like this

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="lblProductLineName" Content="L&iacute;nea de Producto"/>
```

But when i see te user interface don't show me the right character
It must be "**í**"
Anybody can help me with this?

Comment: What is the actual encoding of this file (check it e.g. with notepad++) and what is written in the `<?xml blah ?>` declaration as `encoding="blah"`?

Comment: I use VSCOde to edit .xaml file but inside do not have any encoding tag.

Comment: Okay, and when you open the file with notepad++ and check the actual encoding? What do you see?

Answer (score 1):

You can use unicode versions of the special characters. In your case:

```
<TextBlock Text="Test &#x00CD;"/>
```

[image: Special character WPF]

Wikipedia has a good reference for unicode versions of the special characters: [List of XML and HTML character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Comment: Thaks, but i'm trying to do that. But i got this "L&iacute;nea".

Comment: @D.Hurtado If I get this correctly and you see `L&iacute;nea` where you had entered `L&#00CD;nea` this would show clearly, that the encoding side is working. So I get the feeling that you are reading this XML without the needed re-encoding. How do you read the XML?